# Google Maps public transport in offline mode?

Tags: maps, google-maps

Google Maps is a good ally when traveling. You can download a map for offline and this is nice because when you arrive to a new place and have no internet you can still have access to a map. However, public transportation is not downloaded for offline use. Is it possible?

My current approach is to plan my trip when connected to a Wi-Fi network and take a screenshot.

Comment: Several public transit systems have apps of their own, which may have offline maps.

Comment: There is a pretty old but still very useful offline app for public transport called MetrO http://metro.nanika.net

Comment: Please note that Google _hosts_ the transit data for the local public transportation organisations (Google doesn't produce the data itself), so this data is as good as the organisation provides.  Other mapping providers may or may not rely on the transit authority for their data, so the quality/accuracy may vary greatly.  User beware!

Answer (score 5):

Although Google Maps doesn't do offline public transportation downloading, [OsmAnd](https://osmand.net/) might help you here.  It uses Openstreetmap data.  Depending on the region, Openstreetmap data may be better, equal, or worse than Google Transit data.  On the plus side, if you notice errors, you can go and correct it yourself and others can benefit from your corrections — all data are available under a free license.  You can even go through the effort of checking in advance if the public transportation info for your destination appears up to date (although comparing with reality may be tricky), update Openstreetmap, and then download OsmAnd.

Many transit organisations have their own planning app.  Some may work offline.  Most probably don't.

NB: I have not yet tried OsmAnd for offline public transportation routing.  Personally I plan my public transportation in advance, using online functionality only to find out about current delays, where no offline solution can possibly help.

Answer (score 2):

After quite a lot of searching and testing, this is not possible with Google Maps. Downloading offline maps doesn't download public transport directions.

You can either:

- Take a screenshot of the directions (like you do now)
- Look for another app that can do this

Answer (score 1):

HereWeGo and Moovit both have off-line modes.

HereWeGo is a general-purpose navigation mapping tool and can download maps.

Moovit is public-transportation only, however, it doesn't always work for long-distance trips if they are across its regions.

Comment: Where are there mapping data coming from?  Is it also based on Openstreetmap?

Comment: HereWeGo was Nokia/Ovi maps; it is used in car navigation. It is user-editable. I don't know the underlying source. I don't know where Moovit gets its maps from, but they are mainly for picking your destination